# Highchart Column Range - How to display all of data to join together?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to show `Timeline` data of stock, but my code doesn't work because 
duration of data discontinuous.

This is code that I did;
[`http://codepen.io/patsawalai/pen/WwJJMJ`](http://codepen.io/patsawalai/pen/WwJJMJ)

I want to show data like this picture that all of data to join together;
[`Image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8XRf.jpg)

Comment: I still have no idea what you're actually asking or want to accomplish, or what it is that is the problem. You need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: Due to missing data does not to a timeline. This is overlap (already done) and do not overlap (not shown). @jlbriggs

Comment: @oPim Since missing data is the obstacle - please provide a live example with exemplary data that will be hard coded. Right now it looks like you have incorrect data compering to your expectations. Columns will join each other if they will have proper data. Also, range selector is available in Highstock and not in Highcharts.

Comment: Do you have any advice about bringing highstock in creating this timeline? @KacperMadej

Comment: @oPim Not with inverted chart type - it is not supported by Highstock. But quite similar feature in Highcharts is master-detail - see [the demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail).